# Не выводятся все значения списка

Tags: python, list

Есть вот такой код. По идее ожидаю того, что принт будет выводить каждые элементы, но он выводит только 1, 3, 5

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    
for i in a:
    print(i)
    if i % 2 != 0:
        a.remove(i)


# 1
# 3
# 5
```

Comment: очевидно, потому что вы мутируете список внутри цикла

Comment: Как тогда правильно удалить из листа чётные элементы без создания нового списка?

Comment: Ваш пример не удаляет чётные элементы. Он удаляет нечётные. Чётный остаются. Это чего вы хотите?

Comment: @Эникейщик, в том вопросе есть проблемы с качеством ответов. Здесь ответы куда более проработанные.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy закрыл его как дубликат этого.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я Danis :)

Comment: @Danis, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запомните, что изменять список в процессе итерации по нему - это **очень плохая практика**, потому что чревато многими side-эффектами.

---

##### Что произошло в данном случае?

На первой итерации: `i = 1, i % 2 != 0 -> True`, поэтому удаляется элемент `1` из списка.

В результате чего, список изменится и будет уже другим : `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, далее, для дальнейших рассуждений, нужно понимать, как происходит итерация по списку.

Если коротко: на каждой итерации выбирается элемент **следующий по индексу** (вызывается магический метод `__next__`).

На первой итерации был возвращен элемент с индексом `0`, соответственно на второй итерации - с индексом `1`, и т.д

Но в вашем примере есть один нюанс, вы **изменили исходный список** в процессе итерации по нему, поэтому переход будет выполнен на элемент с индексом `1` уже измененного списка `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` - то есть `3`, в следствие чего был пропущен элемент со значением `2`, так как итератор ничего не знает о том, что исходный список был изменен, и просто сдвигает указатель на следующий индекс.

---

##### Наглядная демонстрация

```
Итерация 1

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 ^                     ^
 i -> print(1)         i

Итерация 2
 
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 x  ^                     
    i -> print(3)
```

---

##### Как же решить задачу без side-эффектов?

Для удаления (фильтрации) элементов по условию можно использовать, например, списковые включения:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a = [x for x in a if x % 2 != 0]

print(a)
```

Или встроенную функцию `filter()`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, a)

print(list(a))
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

---

##### Но это же будет уже новый список?

Да, ссылка изменится, но есть возможность сохранить обновленный список по **старой** ссылке:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(id(a)) # 2089295957248

a[:] = (x for x in a if x % 2 != 0)
print(id(a)) # 2089295957248
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно как-то без списковых включений обойтись?

Comment: @DarkSpace а что вы хотите? почему такое решение не подходит?

Comment: @DarkSpace добавил вариант без создания нового списка

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Кстати, строго говоря, в последнем варианте, если разобрать его по косточкам, новый список все же создается, но затем копируется в исходный и, не оставляет на себя никаких ссылок

Comment: @Александр согласен с вами, стоит написать более конкретно, спасибо!

Comment: `Для удаления (фильтрации)`. можно использовать фукнцию `filter` :)

Answer (score 3):

обходим в обратном порядке:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(a))):
    print(a[i])
    if a[i] % 2:
        a.pop(i)
```

Более выгодно не перестраивать список каждый раз, а "сжимать" его и изменить длину один раз в конце

```
cnt = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] % 2:
        cnt += 1
    else:
        a[i-cnt] = a[i]
del a[-cnt:]
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я не уверен был, что del не делает новый список

Comment: `del` сохраняет старый список. А срез `a = a[...]` меняет `id(a)` что может в некоторых алгоритмах сломать функциональность. Вторая причина выбрать `del` - производительность. `del` в конце списка просто переназначит поле длины списка. Срез скопирует все данные - медленно, двойная память.

Answer (score 2):

##### Анализ

Перепишем код с заменой `for` на `while`. `j` - перебирает индексы в списке. Печать доработана чтобы выводить `j` и список:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

j = 0
while j < len(a):
    i = a[j]
    # print(i)
    print(f'j = {j}, a = {a}, a[j] = {a[j]}')
    if i % 2 != 0:
        a.remove(i)
    j += 1
```

Когда условие истинно, список `a` укорачивается и счётчик `j` увеличивается. Пропускаются элементы:

> ```
> j = 0, a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], a[j] = 1
> j = 1, a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], a[j] = 3
> j = 2, a = [2, 4, 5, 6], a[j] = 5
> ```

##### Копирование исходного списка

Проблема от того что меняется список по которому ведётся цикл. Правим оригинальный цикл. Видите `a[:]` в заголовке цикла?. Теперь итерация ведётся по копии списка и все неприятности исчезают:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    
for i in a[:]:
    print(i)
    if i % 2 != 0:
        a.remove(i)
```

##### Точное управление счётчиком в `while`

Вариант с `while` тоже можно доработать. Он обходится без копирования:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

j = 0
while j < len(a):
    i = a[j]
    # print(i)
    print(f'j = {j}, a = {a}, a[j] = {a[j]}')
    if i % 2 != 0:
        a.remove(i)
    else:
        j += 1
```

> ```
> j = 0, a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], a[j] = 1
> j = 0, a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], a[j] = 2
> j = 1, a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], a[j] = 3
> j = 1, a = [2, 4, 5, 6], a[j] = 4
> j = 2, a = [2, 4, 5, 6], a[j] = 5
> j = 2, a = [2, 4, 6], a[j] = 6
> ```

Хотя всё это работает, я бы не стал так делать. Работает медленно на длинных списках (квадратичная сложность в терминах О-большого). А последний код ещё и сложно устроен.

##### Классика

Индекс `j` будет отставать от итераций в цикле `for` всякий раз когда очередное значение в списке нечётное. В этом случае список тоже меняется во время итерации, но не меняется его длина и "хвост". Этого достаточно, чтобы сюрпризов не было.

Так как во время итерации мы не меняем длину списка в конце его надо обрезать (`del`):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

j = 0
for i in a:
    print(i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        a[j] = i
        j += 1
del a[j:]
```

##### Классика на Питоне

В Питоне есть ещё один способ отфильтровать список "на месте" без использования дополнительной памяти:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(id(a), a)
a[:] = (i for i in a if i % 2 == 0)
print(id(a), a)
```

> ```
> 139721591755968 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> 139721591755968 [2, 4, 6]
> ```

На деле это способ повторяет классический (который с `del`). Не удивлюсь если он окажется самым быстрым - меньше кода, быстрее работает интерпретатор.