Помогите разобраться с кодом!
a = ['egor', 'vika', 'max', 'egor2', 'egor3', 'egor4']

for x in a:
    if x.count('egor') > 0:
        a.remove(x)
    else:
        None
print(a)

По логике результат работы кода должен быть ['vika', 'max'], но по факту результат ['vika', 'max', 'egor3']! Не понимаю откуда берется 'egor3', объясните пожалуйста

Возможно, вы найдете лучшее название для своего вопроса.

Если в блоке else ничего не делается, то он вообще не нужен.

Примечание:
Сначала я исправил и немножко улучшил ваш код:
a = ['egor', 'vika', 'max', 'egor2', 'egor3', 'egor4']

for x in a[:]:                # (исправление)
    if 'egor' in x:           # (улучшение - в том числе и удалением лишней ветви else:)
        a.remove(x)
print(a)

Вывод:

['vika', 'max']



В чем ваша ошибка?
Вы проходите через тот же список, из которого вы удаляете элементы.
Здесь постепенное состояния списка и актуальная позиция (как ^):
a = ['egor', 'vika', 'max', 'egor2', 'egor3', 'egor4']    # перед входом в цикл
  ^

a = ['egor', 'vika', 'max', 'egor2', 'egor3', 'egor4']    # вход  в 1-ю итерацию
       ^

a = [        'vika', 'max', 'egor2', 'egor3', 'egor4']    # вход во 2-ю итерацию -  
               ^                                          # в предыдущей 'egor'удалился
               
a = [        'vika', 'max', 'egor2', 'egor3', 'egor4']    # вход  в 3-ю итерацию
                       ^

a = [        'vika', 'max', 'egor2', 'egor3', 'egor4']    # вход  в 4-ю итерацию
                               ^

a = [        'vika', 'max', 'egor3', 'egor4']             # вход  в 5-ю итерацию - 
                                        ^                 # в предыдущей 'egor2' удалился

a = [        'vika', 'max', 'egor3']                      # выход из 5-й итерации - в ней
                                        ^                 # 'egor4' удалился; актуальная 
                                                          # позиция за концом списка —   
                                                          # нет следующего элемента, 
                                                          # конец цикла

Как вы можете видеть, в списке остались точно те элементы, которые ваша программа и вывела.

Как я это исправил?
Очень просто — вместо вашей команды
for x in a:

я применил
for x in a[:]:


Объяснение:
a[:] сделает из списка a срез из всех элементов, и это копия оригинального списка - и она в цикле не меняется.


Так хорошо  нарисовано, что даже жалко закрывать как дубликат :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1506259/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0

Или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/992441/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-list-remove-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5

Проблема в твоем коде связана с изменением списка (a) во время его итерации в цикле for. Когда ты удаляешь элемент из списка a внутри цикла for, это влияет на индексацию элементов в списке.
Более безопасный способ удаления элементов из списка во время итерации - это создать новый список, содержащий только те элементы, которые ты хочешь сохранить. Вот исправленный код:
a = ['egor', 'vika', 'max', 'egor2', 'egor3', 'egor4']
a = [x for x in a if not x.count('egor') > 0]
print(a)

Этот код удалит все элементы, содержащие подстроку 'egor', и выведет ['vika', 'max'], как ожидалось.
